# Why fread does have thread safe requirements which slows down its call

Tags: c, multithreading

I am writing a function to read binary files that are organized as a succession of (key, value) pairs where keys are small ASCII strings and value are int or double stored in binary format.

If implemented naively, this function makes a lot of call to fread to read very small amount of data (usually no more than 10 bytes). Even though fread internally uses a buffer to read the file, I have implemented my own buffer and I have observed speed up by a factor of 10 on both Linux and Windows. The buffer size used by fread is large enough and the function call cannot be responsible for such a slowdown. So I went and dug into the GNU implementation of fread and discovered some lock on the file, and many other things such as verifying that the file is open with read access and so on. No wonder why fread is so slow.

But what is the rationale behind fread being thread-safe where it seems that multiple thread can call fread on the *same* file which is mind boggling to me. These requirements make it slow as hell. What are the advantages?

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *7.21.2 Streams 7 Each stream has an associated lock that is used to prevent data races when multiple
threads of execution access a stream, and to restrict the interleaving of stream operations
performed by multiple threads. Only one thread may hold this lock at a time. The lock is
reentrant: a single thread may hold the lock multiple times at a given time.*

Comment: @EOF: I understand that it is in the standard. But why does anyone want to access the same file from multiple thread?

Comment: @InsideLoop, it's pretty common for writing to a log file, for example.  All stream I/O functions are thread safe on a per-call basis in part because it wouldn't work for only some of them to be.  And it absolutely could make sense, *especially* with `fread()`, for multiple threads ingesting data from the same file.

Comment: You probably want `stderr` to be thread-safe, or you'll have trouble diagnosing failures. You can also avoid locking in single-threaded code. In multi-threaded code where only one thread writes to any stream regularly, taking the lock will be pretty cheap (because the cache line with the lock will stay with the thread).

Comment: Note also that how much of an impact the locking has on your program depends on its I/O patterns.  If you make many small `fread()` requests then you will be more impacted than if you make fewer, larger ones.  If you perform I/O frequently, no matter the transfer size, you will be proportionally more affected than if I/O were rare.

Comment: @John: I don't buy the fact that it is I/O limited because fread uses an internal buffer so even though you make a lot of calls to get small chunk of data, most of them will give you some data which is already in memory and prevents any I/O.

Comment: @InsideLoop, I said how much of an impact *the locking* has depends on the I/O pattern.  Every call is specified to perform locking, regardless of I/O size or buffering.

Comment: @John: Sorry, got it. I am just extremely surprised that fread has an internal buffer to make calls to get small chunks of data faster and at the same time has so many requirements that cannot make it fast. Note, that I am not sure yet that the locking is the reason why it is so slow. I need further profiling for that.

Comment: Note that if you're on glibc you can use the *_unlocked variants (*e.g.*, `fread_unlocked`). On Windows you can define `_CRT_DISABLE_PERFCRIT_LOCKS`.

Comment: @nemequ: Thank you very much. It allows me to get some speedup, but not as fast as writing my own buffer. But I can go from 270 MB/s with fread to 360 MB/s with fread_unlocked. You could put it as an answer.

Comment: It isn't 'designed to be so slow'. Don't be tendentious. It is designed to be thread-safe. Correctness is more important than speed. You can get the wrong answer in zero time. It's of no interest.

Comment: @EJP: You are right. I work on high performance computing and it turns out that speed is often very important to me. My title was misleading and I have updated it.

Comment: 'I have implemented my own buffer and I have observed speed up by a factor of 10 on both Linux and Windows'...........sounds about right.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have a file where each 5 bytes can be processed in parallel (let's say, pixel by pixel in an image):

123456789A

One thread needs to pick 5 bytes "12345", the next one the next 5 bytes "6789A".

If it was not thread-safe different threads could pick-up wrong chunks. For example: "12367" and "4589A" or even worst (unexpected behaviour, repeated bytes or worst).

Comment: I understand your point, but it does not make sense to read interleaving block of 5 bytes. I would understand 2 threads working on the same file with one processing the first 40 MB and the second one processing the second 40 MB. And I would have two FILE*, one for each thread.

Comment: @InsideLoop Except there are plenty of times when smaller blocks make sense, like the pixels mentioned as an example here. And what if the image is coming in over a pipe?

Comment: I chock this up to the standard library being an 'okay' solution for 'general cases', if you are doing something odd (as would seem the case with reading small unevenly sized blocks from multiple threads) there is likely a better way.

Comment: You're quibbling over the details, @InsideLoop.  The case presented in this answer could be as well addressed by each thread reading 100 5-byte blocks at a time, or more.  The point is that yes, it can make sense for multiple threads to interleave read operations on the same file.

Comment: @John: I understand your point, but I am still puzzled because it turns out that I often write signal processing which works with data coming in real-time such as a pipe, and I have yet to see 2 threads trying to read the same stream.

Comment: @InsideLoop Does not matter if it's 4 bytes at a time or 40MB. Have you considered just using `getc()`? It should be much faster to make a quick loop if you don't need all the extra from `fread()`

Comment: @droperto: I read binary files whereas `getc()` is text-driven.

Comment: @InsideLoop: Without locking, how can you 1. Check if the buffer can satisfy a read, 2. If it can, update the position within the buffer while safely pulling the data, 3. If not, coordinate which thread reads the next block of data into the buffer? And these cases overlap; you might think #2 could be solved with atomics to update the buffer pointer while caching the previous value, then `memcpy`, but if another thread goes to case #3, the buffer might be overwritten between pointer update and `memcpy`. There's no reasonable way to maintain consistent state for the file object without a lock.

Comment: @InsideLoop The standard requires `fread` to behave exactly as if it was calling `fgetc` in a loop.

Comment: If you're on Linux, you can always [use `fread_unlocked`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fread_unlocked) to bypass the lock; if you have some external locking you'll be fine. Or you might be fine by accident for a while, until you race and everything blows up in your face. It's a terrible idea, but you're welcome to play with it for learning purposes.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: I agree with you. I would personally have designed `fread` without any requirement on thread safety. I write a lot of multithreaded code and I don't have a single data structure that is thread safe. I just avoid doing thread-unsafe things on those data structures. It might be a different habit, but locks are prohibited in high performance computing because of the performance penalty. For instance it is very common in HPC to give the same array to 2 different threads and make those threads work on the different parts of the same array.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: In this case, I would be more concerned about opening the same file from 2 different threads which seems to be not allowed by the standard even for reading. I don't know of any mechanism to help you avoid that. This is a real problem and locks won't help you here.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by `nemequ`:

Note that if you're on glibc you can use the _unlocked variants (*e.g., fread_unlocked). On Windows you can define _CRT_DISABLE_PERFCRIT_LOCKS

Answer (score 0):

Stream I/O is already as slow as molasses. Programmers think that a read from main memory (1000x longer than a CPU cycle) is ages. A read from the physical disk or a network may as well be eternity.

I don't know if that's the #1 reason why the library implementers were ok with adding the lock overhead, but I guarantee it played a significant part.

Yes, it slows it down, but as you discovered, you can manually buffer the read and use your own handling to increase the speed when performance really matters. (That's the key--when you absolutely must read the data as fast as possible. Don't bother manually buffering in the general case.)

That's *a* rationalization. I'm sure you could think of more!